# why does the gitk and sourcetree commit graph look different for the same repository

Tags: git, git-commit

Here is my gitk commit graph ( am I using the correct term here, commit graph?)
[image]

and here is my sourcetree commit graph for the same repository
[image]

I am not able to understand why they look different? Shouldn't the `gitk` graph be a straight line? Does something here need to be fixed?

Comment: The local and remote branches do not have to be identical, especially if you are using a merge-based workflow.  What is guaranteed is that if you pull from the remote, then the local and remote branches will be _functionally_ identical (i.e. the source files will all be in sync).

Comment: I know the local and remote dont have to be identical. But what I want to know is why does the graph look cleaner in sourcetree? It shows a clean branch off at the third commit and comes back in nicely in the last commit. The gitk commit graph on the other hand looks wonky. I have always thought that the commit graph should be a straight line of dots, each pertaining to one indivdual commit. Here it looks like something went wrong somewhere. Did it? I can't tell.

Comment: `I can't tell` ... "I can't read it" would be a better description.  This is why many organizations choose to use rebasing instead of merging, because it keeps the history readable.  I can't answer your question without knowing how many merges have been happening locally and on the remote and you yourself may not even know this.

Comment: yes, you are right. I'm sure it means something, but I can't read what it means. At the moment I am the only one working on this repository so when a new branch was created off the master it had the latest commit from the master in it. By the time I finished off on the branch there were no updates on the master ( since I am the only developer on this repo and I did not make any commits to the master) and so I did not think it necessary to do a rebase. I just went and merged it in.

Comment: In a merge based workflow, when you have completed and committed your work, typically you first will `git pull` from the remote to get the latest changes, which creates a merge commit locally.  Then you will issue a pull request which will result in a merge commit on the remote branch.  Of course, other developers will be doing this as well.  Think about this and you will see how messy things can become quickly.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with branching strategy.

Comment: They're the same graph drawn by different people. In git (actually in graphs in general) straight lines have no meaning whatsoever. Only connections between nodes have meaning.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not issue a pull or a pull request.

Comment: @slebetman Do the connections between the nodes here indicate any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what a straight line is.

According to Wikipedia, a graph is:

> In mathematics, and more specifically in graph theory, a graph is a
>   representation of a set of objects where some pairs of objects are
>   connected by links.

Nothing in a graph definition says that the curve of the links or their orientation has any significance.

Only the nodes and the connections between the nodes make the graph.

So what you are comparing is **two different graph representations** of **the same graph**.

When you think about it, it's very unlikely that two different people with two different philosophies and at two different times will implement exactly the same rendering for a graph.
In both case the rendering of the graph depends on how `gitk` or `sourcetree` wants to present the rest of the information and how they decide to order the commits (they need to flatten the graph to display it and thus decide of an arbitrary order for the commits, which doesn't have to be the same).

Comment: These graphs were taken at the same time and from the same repository. I guess I probably need to understand how to read gitk's representation of the commit graph. SourceTree's I do understand as it seems to mimic what I just did; which is ~ a branch off from the master branch ~ made a couple of commits ~ then merged back into master. When it comes to gitk, the order of commits seem to be different. So which one do I trust to be more accurate? Or does it even matter if one puts commit `A` before commit `B` and the other puts commit `B` first and commit `A` later?

Comment: As I said, the order of the commits has no significance. When flattening a graph it's impossible to guarantee that the commits with be displayed in chronological order. If you just focus on the graph, from bottom to top: You have one commit. Then a 2nd one. Then a 3rd one. From the 3rd, there's two branches (left and right has no significance). On each branch, there's one commit. The two branches merge with the 6th commit. That's the description of your graph in words, and it works for both the SourceTree and the Gitk graph. Everything else has no significance.

Comment: It's just that, when flattening, sourcetree and gitk have a different order for the 4th and 5th commit but it doesn't mean anything. `git log` will also have its own arbitrary ordering.

Comment: You can't say which of 4th or 5th commit happened first because there are no before/after links between them, they happen simultaneously, on a graph perspective. The date of the commit is metadata associated to the graph node but has no significance for the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the insight :)